# Google Invisible reCaptcha : bad redirection with Ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, captcha

I want to use Google Invisible reCaptcha with my Magento for the registration form.

I download this extension : https://amasty.com/magento-google-invisible-captcha.html

I configure in my BO and that works fine for non-Ajax form. But if I use Ajax form, the redirection back to my page not work : I stay on the Ajax page which display {"success":true,"} (or false if there is mistake in the form).

How can I configure my extension to force the redirection back my page after the Ajax ?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @akgola > It was a configuration issue but I not remerber exactly what I did. Do you have the same issue ? What is your configuration ?

Comment: yes I have same issue.Please check in link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/221065/24878  and please let me know if you have any solution.